# system-properties in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

In the `standlone.xml` file in JBoss AS7, I have set the variable `my.dir` in system properties as

```
<system-properties>
<property name="my.dir" value="D:\\mylocation"
</system-properties>
```

Now I am trying to use this variable to specify the location of the keystore file in the standalone.xml in the following way

```
certificate-key-file="${my.dir}\cert\mycert.keystore"
```

However, while starting JBoss, I am getting `IO exception` as JBoss is not able to locate the path. Could you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the ssl element in the jboss web subsystem does not support system property substitution (yet). You have 3 choices:

- Use an absolute path
- Use a relative path from `$JBOSS_AS7\bin` location
- Store the certificate in the default location where JBoss looks for them - `${user.home}/.keystore` which is the operating system home directory the user running `jboss.web`.

See more details on jboss.web ssl configuration [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/ssl-howto.html).